# Closed form for $\int \left(1-x^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}\:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

Find a closed-form solution to
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \left(1-x^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}\:dx\tag{1},\end{align}
or even more generally, is there a methodology to solving integrals of the type
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\left(1-x^r\right)^{1/r}\:dx,\:\:r\in\left\{s\in\mathbb{Q}:0<s<1\right\}.\tag{2}
\end{align}
This integral arose when trying to calculate the area of a Superellipse.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: In full generality, the change of variable $x=t^{1/r}$ shows that $$\int_0^1\left(1-x^r\right)^{1/r}\:dx=\frac1r\int_0^1\left(1-t\right)^{1/r}t^{1/r-1}\:dr=\frac1r\mathrm{B}(1/r,1+1/r).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through the [Euler's Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) it is not difficult to show (like in [this closed question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149438/integrate-how-to-prove/1149502#1149502)) that for any $p,q>0$ we have:

$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^p)^{\frac{1}{q}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^q)^{\frac{1}{p}}\,dx =\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{q}\right)}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}\right)} $$

hence by choosing $p=q=\frac{2}{3}$ we have:
$$ I = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma(4)} = \color{red}{\frac{3\pi}{32}}$$
and if $p=q=r$
$$ I = \frac{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{r}\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{2}{r}\right)}=\frac{r}{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{r}\right)}=\frac{r\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{2/r}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{r}\right)} $$
by [Legendre's duplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I liked your reference to the Beta function and I learned something new via that link (I will remember that identity).

Answer (score 5):

Since $x\leq1$
 , we can try $x=\sin^{3}\left(y\right)$
  and then $dx=3\sin^{2}\left(y\right)\cos\left(y\right)dy$
 , whence$$\intop\left(1-x^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}dx=3\intop\cos^{4}\left(y\right)\sin^{2}\left(y\right)dy.$$
Maybe this last integral is easier to work.

Answer (score 2):

The (most) general answer involves the hypergeometric function $_pF_q$:
\begin{equation}
\int(1-x^r)^{1/r} dx=x\;_2F_1(-1/r,1/r,1+1/r,x^r)
\end{equation}
In the particular case of (1) the indefinite integral is given by:
\begin{equation}
\int(1-x^{2/3})^{3/2} dx=\frac{1}{16}\left(\sqrt{1-x^{2/3}}(-3x^{1/3}+14x-8x^{5/3})+3\arcsin(x^{1/3})\right)
\end{equation}
Evaluation at $0$ and $1$ gives us:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^{2/3})^{3/2} dx=\frac{3\pi}{32}
\end{equation}
And more generally:

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^r)^{1/r} dx=\frac{\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{r})^2}{\Gamma(\frac{2+r}{r})}
\end{equation}
Where $\Gamma(x)=(x-1)!$ is the extension of the factorial function.

More information about the hypergeometric and gamma function can be found on: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html

Comment: Sorry but the value of the integral cannot depend on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

This integral may belong within a special category. See a general case in  [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107503/evaluate-intx-sqrt1-x4dx/1107552#1107552) here.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^1(1-x^r)^\frac{1}{r}~dx$

$=\int_0^1(1-x)^\frac{1}{r}~d\left(x^\frac{1}{r}\right)$

$=\dfrac{1}{r}\int_0^1x^{\frac{1}{r}-1}(1-x)^\frac{1}{r}~dx$

$=\dfrac{1}{r}B\left(\dfrac{1}{r},\dfrac{1}{r}+1\right)$

Comment: Nice substitution! That's one I would never have thought of..